# how to view content of object using TotalView?

Tags: c++, totalview

how to view content of object using TotalView? suppose i hav a Reference of a class and i called the function of that class. then how i can view all content of that class using that Reference in Total View debugger. My code is in c++.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to double-click on the variable: it will pop-up a window with the contents.  Note that you need to have built your application with debug symbols turned on.

Comment: yes it is but i have class Reference and from that i need to look in to that class bye passing this pointer of that class. can resolve it..